# Login to Exchnage 2013 mailbox using Micosoft.Exchange.Windows.Service.dll

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am working on C# windows application. I need to login to Exchnage Server 2013 and populate mailboxes using my application.

Here is the sample code

```
private void connect()
{
  ExchangeService objservice = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
  objservice.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username","password");
  objservice.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
  objservice.AutodiscoverUrl("userEmailAddress",RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
}

private bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(String redirectionUrl)
        {

            return (redirectionUrl == @"https://Exch2013machine.domain.local/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

        }
```

But when service calls the AutodiscoverURL i get error as ": **The Autodiscover service couldn't be located"**. I have check the environment settings and found that Autodiscover is running in IIS on Exchange server. Is there any thing else need to be done to login to Exchnage server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have Outlook? You can ctrl+click the outlook icon in your notification bar and choose "Test e-mail configuration" and confirm that the URL is coming through. Also, for testing purposes just use `objservice.AutodiscoverUrl("emailAddress", x => true);` (the URL you're expecting may be off by a domain or a webfarm namespace). If it succeeds, output `objservice.Url` and see what you're left with moving forward.

Comment: More findings: When I try to connect to Office 365 using Microsoft.Exchnage.Webservice.dll Autodiscover is working but not with Exchange 2013

Comment: As in exchange the client (Office365 suite)? (I'm a little confused by your wording).

Comment: Your RedirectionUrlValidationCallback will only work with a very specific redirect. In many cases, there will be many redirects. I second what Brad said when it comes to testing.